# What is the issue with my foreach in Scala code

Tags: scala

Below is my scala code, but line 13, there is an error says "missing parameter type", not sure what my problem?

```
class OneAway {

  def isOneAway(s1:String, s2:String):Boolean={
    if(s1.equals(s2))
        return true
    else if( s1.length > s2.length + 1 || s1.length < s2.length - 1)
      return false
    else 
    {
      var count:Int=0
  s1.chars().forEach(a=>{
        if(a!=s2.charAt(count)){         
            return  s2.substring(count+1).equals(s1.substring(count)) ||    s1.substring(count+1).equals(s2.substring(count))
        }
        count=count+1
      }
        )      
      return true
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foreach` should be all lowercase, plus lose the curly braces inside of it.

Also, even though you didn't ask ... This is a horrible way to write scala code. In 99% of the cases you'll ever run into, you'll want to avoid using returns, mutable state, and (with some exceptions) indexed access to sequences. 
Your code will also throw illegal index exceptions in some cases.

A proper way to do what you want in scala would be something like this:

```
@tailrec
def isOneAway(s1: String, s2: String): Boolean = (s1.headOption, s2.headOption) match {
  case (None, None) => true
  case (a,b) if a == b => isOneAway(s1.tail, s2.tail)
  case _ if s1.length == s2.length + 1 => s1.tail == s2
  case _ if s2.length == s1.length + 1 => s2.tail == s1        
  case _ => false
}
```

Comment: This is more accurate answer in scala world. In most of the cases you will have to avoid if.. else structure.

Comment: May I know what does the last three cases mean? Thanks.

Comment: What trips you up about them? If second string is shorter by one char drop first character from it, and compare the rest. If first string is shorted by one, drop it's first char and compare the rest. Otherwise the lengths are not off by one, so just return false.

Comment: Thanks@Dima, I am new to scala, it is indeed very helpful for me, is there any good material for me to start with scala?

Comment: Plenty ... :) https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=scala%20books
(I am NOT kidding: at the level of our discussion here, any of those books will be helpful).

Answer (score 3):

should be

```
s1.foreach(a=>{....})
```

chars() is from java8 and you are using scala. You can simply use foreach on String object.